# Equality for a DateOfBirth Value Object

Tags: c#

Please see the code below:

```
public sealed class DateOfBirth : IEquatable<DateOfBirth>, IComparable<DateOfBirth>
    {
        private readonly DateTime _value;
        public DateOfBirth(DateTime dateOfBirth)
        {
            if(dateOfBirth == DateTime.MinValue)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid value.", "DateOfBirth");
            this._value= dateOfBirth.date;
        }

        public DateTime Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
        }

        private static int Comparison(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth1, dateOfBirth2))
                return 0;
            else if (ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth1, null))
                return -1;
            else if (ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth2, null))
                return 1;
            if (dateOfBirth1._value < dateOfBirth2._value)
                return -1;
            else if (dateOfBirth1._value == dateOfBirth2._value)
                return 0;
            else if (dateOfBirth1._value > dateOfBirth2._value)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }

        public int CompareTo(DateOfBirth other)
        {
            if (other != null)
                return this._value.CompareTo(other._value);
            else
                throw new ArgumentNullException("DateOfBirth");
        }


        public static bool operator ==(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
        {
            return Comparison(dateOfBirth1, dateOfBirth2) == 0;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
        {
            return !(dateOfBirth1 == dateOfBirth2);
        }

        public static bool operator <(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
        {
            return Comparison(dateOfBirth1, dateOfBirth2) < 0;
        }

        public static bool operator >(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
        {
            return Comparison(dateOfBirth1, dateOfBirth2) > 0;
        }

        public static bool operator <=(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
        {
            return Comparison(dateOfBirth1, dateOfBirth2) <= 0;
        }

        public static bool operator >=(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
        {
            return Comparison(dateOfBirth1, dateOfBirth2) >= 0;
        }

        public bool Equals(DateOfBirth other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
                return false;
            return _value == other._value;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return Equals(obj as DateOfBirth);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return _value.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

I realise it could be argued as over engineering a simple date of birth field. I am more interested whether or not the nine comparisons (https://ericlippert.com/2013/10/07/math-from-scratch-part-six-comparisons/) are implemented correctly. This article helped me: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2005/10/11/c-comparison-operator-overloading-and-spaceship-operator/ - the only concern I have about the code in this article is that the Comparison method does not do this (which my code does):

```
if (ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth1, dateOfBirth2))
                return 0;
            else if (ReferenceEquals(dateOfBirth1, null))
```

Comment: Would this be something for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: You are comparing the time component of the DateTime as well as the Date component, so this won't work as date of birth is just a date, and does not include time.

Comment: Why aren't you using date1.CompareTo(date2)

Comment: You may want to double-check your `>=` operator. You may also want to add some year, month and day properties, for obvious reasons.

Comment: This class definitely needs a lot more `.Date` behind its DateTime object usages, yes.

Comment: @Nyerguds, I have edited the question with your suggestion.  I assume that has fixed it?

Comment: @Pieter Witvoet, is this so I can compare different country dates?

Comment: @w0051977 1) compare the bodies of the `<=` and `>=` operators (they are now equal - good catch by Pieter); 2) you have no way to *show* or *read* the date - you can only *compare*

Comment: @w0051977: what Hans said is exactly what I was hinting at. Not being able to observe the actual date makes this class fairly useless.

Comment: @Hans Kesting, I have corrected the code.  Could you take another look?

Comment: @Pieter Witvoet, what do you mean: "Not being able to observe the actual date makes this class fairly useless"? Do I need to add a public property exposing _value?

Comment: @w0051977: isn't it obvious? If you ask me for my birthday, and I reply 'it's after 1900, before 2000, and it's not on November 3rd, 1960', is that a useful answer?

Comment: @Pieter Witvoet, yes it is - I did not realise that I had missed the getter (I was confused why you were asking).  Sorry about that.  I have updated the code.  Does the class look more worthwhile now?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to handle all those comparisons yourself. Instead, delegate the comparison work to the underlying `DateTime _value`.

MSDN contains comprehensive documentation about [how to override `Equals` method and overload `==` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh(v=vs.100).aspx). I don't think there is anything to add to this documentation. Again, since you're relying on an underlying value which supports comparisons, your:

```
public static bool operator ==(DateOfBirth dateOfBirth1, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth2)
{
    return Comparison(dateOfBirth1, dateOfBirth2) == 0;
}
```

could be written simply as:

```
public static bool operator ==(DateOfBirth d1, DateOfBirth d2)
{
    return d1._value == d2._value;
}
```

Similarly, `DateTime` itself simply [delegated the comparison to `long`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,1225):

```
public struct DateTime : ...
{
    ...
    public static bool operator ==(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
    {
        return d1.InternalTicks == d2.InternalTicks;
    }
}
```

Note that since `DateTime` is a `struct`, you know that you'll always have a value in `_value` field. Things would be different if you were using a `class`: in that case, the easiest way would be to forbid `null` values inside the constructor; handling them in comparison methods would be possible too, but would require more code and would be more error prone.

---

By the way, make sure you have a good reason to make `DateOfBirth` a class, and not a `struct`, as well as marking it sealed.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to override all nine comparison operators? I.e. <, >, <=, >=, inequality.equals etc.